# Speeding up Arcpy python Script, Big Data

Tags: python, bigdata, arcpy

I have a ridiculously simple python script that uses the arcpy module. I turned it into a script tool in arcmap and am running it that way. It works just fine, I've tested it multiple times on small datasets. The problem is that I have a very large amount of data. I need to run the script/tool on a .dbf table with 4 columns and 490,481,440 rows, and currently it has taken days. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed it up? To save time I've already created the columns that will be populated in the table before I run the script. "back" represents the second number after the comma in the "back_pres_dist" column and "dist" represents the fourth. All I want is for them to be in their own separate columns. The table and script look something like this:

```
back_pres_dist       back     dist
1,1,1,2345.6
1,1,2,3533.8
1,1,3,4440.5
1,1,4,3892.6
1,1,5,1292.0




import arcpy
from arcpy import env

inputTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
back1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #the empty back column to be populated
dist3 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #the empty dist column to be populated

arcpy.CalculateField_management(inputTable, back1, '!back_pres_dist!.split(",")[1]', "PYTHON_9.3")
updateMess = arcpy.AddMessage("back column updated.")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inputTable, dist3, '!back_pres_dist!.split(",")[3]', "PYTHON_9.3")
updateMess = arcpy.AddMessage("dist column updated.")

updateMess = arcpy.AddMessage("All columns updated.")
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I know that reading some parts of the data into memory might speed things up, but I'm not sure how to do that with python (when using R it took forever to read into memory and was a nightmare trying to write to a .csv).

Comment: Does anyone know if this would be faster if I just strictly used it as python without turning it into an arcMap tool? Would it make a difference? Still hoping for any suggestions that might speed this up.

Comment: You should use [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000) in the data access module if you want to continue to do it in arcpy. That should cut your process time roughly in half (I suspect even more). When you run calculate field, it's iterating over every row. Since you call it twice, you're iterating your entire table twice.

Comment: Oh, that's really strange, I was using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor before but read somewhere that the calculate field would be more efficient (that is was the other way around where the da.UpdateCursor read by row). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a ton of data. I'm guessing that your main bottleneck is read/write operations on the disk and not CPU or memory.

Your process appears to modify each row independently according to constant input values in what's essentially a tabular operation that doesn't really require GIS functionality. As a result, I would definitely look at doing this outside of the `arcpy` environment to avoid that overhead. While you could dump this stuff to numpy with the new `arcpy.da` functionality, I think that even this might be a bottleneck. Seems you should be able to more directly read your *.dbf file with a different library.

In fact, this operation is not really tabular; it's really about iteration. You'll probably want to exploit things like the "WITH"/"AS" keywords (PEP 343, Raymond Hettinger has a good video on youtube, too) or iterators in general (see PEPs 234, 255), which only load a record at a time.

Beyond those general programming approaches, I'm thinking that your best bet would be to break this data into chunks, parallelize, and then reassemble the results. Part of engineering the parallelization could be to spread your data across different disk platters to avoid competing between i/o requests. [iPython](http://ipython.org/) is an add-on for python that has a pretty easy to use, high-level pacakge, "parallel", if you want an easy place to start. Lots of pretty good videos on youtube from PyCon 2012. There's a  [3 hour one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2G5YTlheCbw) where the parallel stuff starts at 2:13:00 or so.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for all the helpful info. I don't often work with this much data so it has been a struggle. Hopefully doing it without arcpy and with chunks and parallelization will do the trick.

Comment: Sure thing. Definitely check that video out and talk w/someone who's messed w/parallelizing. It's a different way of thinking. Other parallel packages might work as well as better, too, especially if you or a helper has got fluency in something other than what I mentioned. Might search stackoverflow or gisstackexchange for dbf reader packages, too.